# Pass angular data between service to controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-services

i have my angular service and controller, i need to pass the data between service to controller to get value for voucher_code

Angular Service:

```
myApp.service('tradeData', function ($http) {
var service ={};
var voucher_code;
service.postTrade = function(trade){
   console.log(trade)
   console.log("TEST")
   var promise = $http.post('tradein', trade);

   promise.
   then(function successCallback(response) {
       angular.extend(trade, response.tradeData);
        //console.log("======="+response.data)

    voucher_code = JSON.stringify(response.data.voucher_code, null, 4); // (Optional) beautiful indented output.
    console.log("test123",voucher_code);
        return voucher_code;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });

   return promise;
 };
 return service;

})
```

Angular Controller:

```
myApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items, PersonalInfoService, tradeData) {
$scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}
$scope.personal = PersonalInfoService;
$scope.printToCart = function(printSectionId) {
    var innerContents = document.getElementById(printSectionId).innerHTML;
    var popupWinindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=550,height=700,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
    popupWinindow.document.open();
    popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="screen, print" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + innerContents + '</html>');
    popupWinindow.document.close();
}

$scope.Product = tradeData;
console.log("sfsdff" , tradeData.voucher_code);
// console.log("santo", voucher_code);
// console.log("santo", service);
})
```

Any idea to pass the values of voucher_code from service to controller

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your controller:

```
tradeData.postTrade().then(function(voucher_code) {
   $scope.voucher_code = voucher_code;
)};
```

`postTrade` method returns the promise. So you can use the data it returns (get resolved with) by using the `then` method.